# Read from Google PubSub and then read from Bigtable based on the PubSub message Topic

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub, apache-beam, google-cloud-bigtable

In Beam(Dataflow 2.0.0), I am reading a PubSub topic and then trying to fetch few rows from Bigtable based on the message from the topic. I couldn't find a way to scan the BigTable based on the pubsub messages through Beam documentation. I tried to write ParDo function and pipe it into the beam pipeline but in vain.

The BigTableIO gives an option of read but that is outside of pipeline and am not sure it would work in the steaming fashion as my use-case.

Can anyone please let me know if this is doable as in streaming PubSub and read BigTable based on the message content.

P.S: I am using Java API in Beam 2.0.

```
    PCollection<String> keyLines = 
                pipeline.apply(PubsubIO.readMessagesWithAttributes()
                .fromSubscription("*************"))
                .apply("PubSub Message to Payload as String", 
                     ParDo.of(new PubSubMessageToStringConverter()));
```

Now I want the keyLines to act as the row keys to scan the BigTable. I am using the below code snippet from BigTable. I can see 'RowFilter.newBuilder()' and 'ByteKeyRange'  but both of them seems work in batch mode not in streaming fashion.

```
   pipeline.apply("read",
                BigtableIO.read()
                     .withBigtableOptions(optionsBuilder)
                     .withTableId("**********");

    pipeline.run();
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to read from BigTable in a ParDo. You would have to use Cloud Big Table or HBase API directly. It is better to initialize the client in `@Setup` method in your DoFn ([example](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/apis)). Please post more details if it does not work.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I have added my code snippet. It would be better if you can clarify.

Comment: I don't think you can use `BigtableIO.read()` source that way. In your case does each 'keyLine' provide a single key that you want to look up, or does each it represents a potentially large scan that you would like to use BigtableIO.read() to scan? If it is the former, an explicit bigtable look up in a `ParDo` is good (using Bigtable API directly). The later is doable in Beam using new API for sources ([Splittable DoFn](https://s.apache.org/splittable-do-fn])), but there is no ready made implementation that handles your use case yet (i.e for each line launch a Bitatble reader).